# pycharm is not getting started on windows 10

Tags: java, python, windows, pycharm

Tried to install Pycharm and Intellij freshly , but after installing it, applications are not getting started when I click on launcher. Also system has crested on error_in_pycharm_2484.log file which has following body :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd4303f183, pid=4284, tid=15108
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.5+10) (build 11.0.5+10-b520.17)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.5+10-b520.17, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, concurrent mark sweep gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x59f183]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: exit -Xms128m -Xmx2023m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Users\pyadgire\.PyCharmCE2019.3\config\pycharm64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\jbr\\bin\server -Didea.platform.prefix=PyCharmCore -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.paths.selector=PyCharmCE2019.3 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\pyadgire\java_error_in_pycharm_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\pyadgire\java_error_in_pycharm.hprof 

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8365U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 8 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 16299 (10.0.16299.1146)
Time: Wed Apr  8 20:48:55 2020 India Standard Time elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000004d89800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=15108, stack(0x0000000000050000,0x0000000000150000)]

Stack: [0x0000000000050000,0x0000000000150000],  sp=0x000000000014c320,  free space=1008k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x59f183]
V  [jvm.dll+0x59e120]
C  0x0000000008c1f077

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.expand(Ljava/lang/invoke/MemberName;)V+0 java.base@11.0.5
j  java.lang.invoke.MemberName.expandFromVM()V+17 java.base@11.0.5
j  java.lang.invoke.MemberName.getMethodType()Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;+8 java.base@11.0.5
j  java.lang.invoke.MemberName.checkForTypeAlias(Ljava/lang/Class;)V+30 java.base@11.0.5
j  java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(BLjava/lang/invoke/MemberName;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/invoke/MemberName;+58 java.base@11.0.5
```

Please help me in how can I resolve it. This happening from long back !!
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION usually happens when loading some native code goes wrong and that may happen if you are low on memory or if there is some hard bug somewhere.

However, what helped on other bugs was just deleting the .idea folder in a project, but in your case, it sounds like the entire IDE isn't starting anymore.

Therefore, I suggest filling a ticket with JetBrains as this is most likely outside the average scope of bugs. I am working with JetBrains IDE's for almost ten years and have never seen this one.

Comment: I raised a ticket on http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp as suggested in the log. Deleting .idea folder in project did not work!!

Comment: It's unlikely Oracle will move within a reasonable time, but it's always good practice to report. I see that you use Java 11. Can you upgrade to a more recent Java version i.e. 15?
Occasionally, it does the trick.